# ignore blank cells when counting dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to calculate dates between dates. column C has some empty cells. How can I change my formula to ignore the dates

```
=DATEDIF(B2,C2,"D")
```

Thanks for helping out

Comment: How do you want to treat the difference of values when one value is empty? You can wrap your function in `IFERROR` and provide an error-case handling.

Comment: `=IF(C2="","",C2-B2)`

Comment: Thanks:) =IF(C2="","",C2-B2) works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Office 365 version of Excel / equivalent, then you could use something like the following:

```
=LET(diff,C8-B8,IF(diff<0,"",diff))
```

Otherwise go for:

```
=if(C8-B8<0,"",C8-B8)
```

OR, more simply:

```
=if(C8 = "", "", C8 - B8)
```

(per @Craner comment), which is equivalent to:

```
=if(isblank(C8),"",C8 - B8)
```